after removing Edge, the start menu button stopped working
I'm running Windows 11 in a virtual machine (KVM/QEMU). I have no intention to use Edge so I have removed it (and EdgeUpdate, EdgeView etc) from the VM.
Now the start menu button does not work any more -- the left-click action that is, I still get a list of actions when I right-click it?
Could this be due to the graphics of the Start Menu button using Edge for graphics?
If I could restore the button functionality without reinstalling Edge that would be great, otherwise I'm happier without both!

Likely post hoc ergo propter hoc...

If you care, there are great replacements for the Start button and menu, such as Open-Shell, https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/.

“ Could this be due to the graphics of the Start Menu button using Edge for graphics?” - No, Microsoft fully supports removing Edge, definitely it the way you did it, but there is an approved process

Thanks for all your helpful comments. One thing that did solve it for me was installing startallback. It has not got rid of the problem (after uninstalling it the first time, the start menu did not work again) but it does the job for now :)

It's definitely something to do with Edge @Ramhound, because in Default Apps it says that there is no app that can handle the search bar either, as an alternative to Edge. Luckily I can switch off the search bar as well.

I really like the look of Open-Shell @DrMoishePippik! May switch to that later - for now I went a bit more minimalistic.

@alle_meije - Removed Edge 6 months ago from my own system I wasn’t able to reproduce the behavior you described. You made no mention of the “no default approach” prompt.

No, true. I only found out later that the serach bar did not work either. Really curious what the approved way of removing Edge is! In my VM the 'uninstall' option was greyed out.
